# Pass objects as parameter to a generic object

Tags: c#

I would like to pass an object which has a method setName to a generic type of object. An example:

```
//Instead of obj.setName = "John"; do this:
aMethod(obj);
aMethod(different_obj); //different_obj has also a method setName
public aMethod(object anOtherObj) {
   anOtherObj.setName = "John";
   Console.Writeline(anOtherObj.setName);
}
```

Comment: How this is related to generics?

Comment: You are right it's not it was suggested but the site. I removed it.

Comment: Elaborate a little. You could do this with `dynamic`, with an interface or with generics. But the code is to short and too simplified to make a decision.

Comment: I would like to fill a richtextbox with parameters of objects, i want instead of copy/paste the same code of richtextbox.appendtext(obj.name) again and again to have a generic obj and pass my objects there. In a single method with few lines. The objects are of different type though. But with the same methods.

Comment: @George: can you re-design your objects to implement interface like `INamedObject`?

Comment: "The objects are of different type ..." - OK, which types, are they yours, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your method with dynamic argument:

```
public void Method(dynamic anotherObj) 
{
     anotherObj.Name = "John";
     Console.Writeline(anotherObj.Name);
}
```

Also from your syntax, I assume `setName` isn't actually a method, it is either property or field, so better name for it would be `Name`.

Anyway going this way isn't a good practise at all. If those different classes have same field, just extract base class or interface for them, and use it as a parameter type in your method.

Comment: I am going for something simple as possible.